# Puzzled by CSS selector to trigger controller

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I'm having trouble understanding how an attribute selector can be used to restrict the scope of a controller. Here's the minimal controller code:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgDirective(
  selector: '[my-controller]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MyController {
  String foo = 'fooooooooooooo';
}

main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new Module()
      ..type(MyController));
}
```

And here is the view that uses that controller:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div> 

      <!-- DOES NOT WORK. MAKES SENSE. -->           
      <p>Outside ng-app: {{ctrl.foo}}</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-app>
      <div my-controller>
        <!-- WORKS. MAKES SENSE -->           
        <p>Inside my-controller div: {{ctrl.foo}}</p>
      </div>

      <!-- WORKS. WHY? It is outside the div with the my-controller attribute -->
      -->
      <p>Outside my-controller div: {{ctrl.foo}}</p>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Predictably, the `{{ctrl.foo}}` code does not work outside the element with the `ng-app`. Also predictably, `{{ctrl.foo}}` works inside `<div my-controller>`. But I don't understand why it works *outside* `<div my-controller>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes this is indeed a bug :-( https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/396

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `NgDirective` not `NgController`. `NgDirective` does not create its own scope and hence the leak. Switching to `NgController` should solve the issue.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue lies in the fact @NgDirective does not create it's own scope...

Try @NgComponent and move your: 
    "Inside my-controller div: {{ctrl.foo}}"
into its template property.