# Angular.Dart - Undefined name 'ctrl'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying out several GitHub samples and running into the same problem, I haven't changed the code and the related dart files are OK.

As example:

```
  <li ng-repeat="module in ctrl.modules"><a href="#{{ module.name }}">{{ module.displayName }}</a></li>
```

I get this error from html page : 'Undefined name 'ctrl'

What am I not understanding?

GitHub repository in question: [Here](https://github.com/bwu-dart/angular_ui_bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

You need a controller on a parent tag that is published as 'ctrl'

here is a simple example: [Do publishAs values have to be unique in Angular Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009394)

Your snippet is from https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui.demo/blob/master/web/index.html and the data is from https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui.demo/blob/master/lib/app/main_ctrl.dart and the controller published as 'ctrl' is on the body tag `ng-controller='main-ctrl'`

Comment: I took it straight out of GitHub, I did not change anything. One was even yours Gunter

Comment: Do you have a link to the concrete file where you've got it from? I guess you should have taken a little more. It's just missing its context.

Comment: Searching now. Specifically, I was looking for one with JSON involved. I saw a SO you listed, I think reg. movies, but I did not notice a link of your corrected solution.

Comment: IDK, very disconcerted about Angular.Dart. I'm gonna pass on this technology for a while.